# Nifi cluster configuration

Tags: apache-nifi

I am currently running one cluster with two nodes on one VM, both nodes are listing to different Ports, one is on port 80 and one is on port 81. My firewall is configured to allow port 80 communications through. With that being said, if I disconnect the node of port 80 the UI sends me this message “This node is currently not connected to the cluster. Any modifications to the data flow made here will not replicate across the cluster.” But the process in the background connects to the new node and keeps running normally, and the Canvas (UI) bugs out and I get a “disconnection message in the top left of the screen, where it would usually show you how many nodes you have running, but if I disconnect the node on port 81, everything runs smoothly. Not sure if both nodes need to be on the same Port or not, or if both nodes need to be on the same port but different VMs. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Apache NiFi 1.x clustering](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#clustering) follows a zero-master design.  Each of the cluster nodes runs an active NiFi process, and each runs the web and API server on their port (80 and 81 here).  Because you are running the two processes on the same physical machine, they require different ports.

As you communicate with the NiFi process on port 80 - changing the flow, starting/stopping processors, etc - it will coordinate these changes with the NiFi process on port 81.  If you connected to the UI on port 81, you would see your changes reflected, and you would also be able to make updates that are coordinated across the cluster.

If you remove a node from the cluster, this coordination no longer involves that node.

Typically, you would expose the web UI/API port of each of the cluster nodes, so that if one node fails or is disconnected, you can continue to administer the cluster through any other active, healthy node.